# Pass large string from cpp into js through JSI in react native

Tags: javascript, c++, react-native

I have a problem in New Architecture. When i trigger function from cpp to JS with large `data`. it spent a lot of times transitting it to js (20-40 miliseconds). There are solutions for this problem for this.

[image: source code]

nothing to expected.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: What does it mean large? Did you profile your code properly? Are you sure conversion is main bottleneck? How did you do this measurement? Quality of question suggests that problem might be something else.

Answer (score 0):

What can I suggest based on your problem:

#### Use Typed Arrays

- Modify your C++ code to use typed arrays (e.g., Uint8Array, Int32Array) for data transfer.
  Pass the typed array from C++ to JavaScript using the JSI.

#### Serialize/Deserialize

- Serialize the data in C++ before passing it to JavaScript if it can be represented in a serialized format (e.g., JSON).
- Deserialize the data in JavaScript to reconstruct the original data structure.

#### Transfer Data in Chunks

- Split the large data into smaller chunks for transfer.
- Transfer the chunks sequentially from C++ to JavaScript.
- Concatenate the received chunks in JavaScript to reconstruct the complete data.

#### Use Shared Memory

- If supported by your target platforms (e.g., Android, iOS with JSI), investigate shared memory mechanisms like SharedArrayBuffer or mmap.
- Use shared memory to directly share memory between C++ and JavaScript without data copying.

#### Implement Native Module

- If the performance is still unsatisfactory, consider implementing a native module directly in Java (for Android) or Objective-C/Swift (for iOS).
- Write platform-specific code in the native module to handle the data transfer.
- Access the native module directly from JavaScript to bypass the JSI bridge.